# Select between values in 2 columns based on a conditional in third column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda

How do I select between 2 columns based on a conditional in third column using pandas ?

In excel I would use something like :
NEW_COLUMN = IF (CONDITION == TRUE ,  COLUMN 1 , COLUMN 2). I am not able to use lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['NEW_COLUMN'] = np.where(CONDITION, df['COLUMN 1'] , df['COLUMN 2'])
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL':[4,5,4],
                   'COLUMN 1':[7,8,9],
                   'COLUMN 2':[1,3,5],})


df['NEW_COLUMN'] = np.where(df['COL'] == 4, df['COLUMN 1'] , df['COLUMN 2'])
print (df)
   COL  COLUMN 1  COLUMN 2  NEW_COLUMN
0    4         7         1           7
1    5         8         3           3
2    4         9         5           9
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Series.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) method:

```
In [251]: df['NEW_COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN 1'].where(df['COL']==4, df['COLUMN 2'])

In [252]: df
Out[252]:
   COL  COLUMN 1  COLUMN 2  NEW_COLUMN
0    4         7         1           7
1    5         8         3           3
2    4         9         5           9
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to set your default column value, then use `.loc` accessor to update depending on your condition.

Data from @jezrael.

```
df['NEW_COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN 2']
df.loc[df['COL'] == 4, 'NEW_COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN 1']

#    COL  COLUMN 1  COLUMN 2  NEW_COLUMN
# 0    4         7         1           7
# 1    5         8         3           3
# 2    4         9         5           9
```